# Solving Equi task in python

Tags: python, list, math, complexity-theory

From http://blog.codility.com/2011/03/solutions-for-task-equi.html

The task is to solve an equilibrium problem. The equilibrium index of a sequence is an index such that the sum of elements at lower indexes is equal to the sum of elements at higher indexes.

For example, in a sequence A:

```
A[0]=-7 A[1]=1 A[2]=5 A[3]=2 A[4]=-4 A[5]=3 A[6]=0
```

i.e.

```
A = [-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0]
```

3 is an equilibrium index, because:

```
 A[0]+A[1]+A[2]=A[4]+A[5]+A[6]
```

6 is also an equilibrium index, because:

```
A[0]+A[1]+A[2]+A[3]+A[4]+A[5]=0
```

When I try to write a super pythonic answer, i.e.:

```
def solution(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if sum(A[:i]) == sum(A[i+1:]):
            return i 
    return -1
```

I get a worst-case complexity of `O(N**2)`. **Why is that so?**

**How do I get a best case complexity of `O(N)`?**

Does this give me `O(N)`? **Why is that so?**

```
def solution(A):
    total = sum(A)
    sum_left = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        sum_right = sum - sum_left
        if sum_left == sum_right:
            return i
    return -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your solution is `O(N)` and it's because you iterate through the list only once and each iteration is `O(1)`. Your previous solution also iterated through the list one but it summed all elements inside each iteration which made each iteration `O(N)` too, resulting in the total complexity of `O(N^2)`.

But I think your solution is wrong - you are not accumulating the `sum_left`. You have to add `A[i]` inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Just to adjust Hugh's answer slightly, the exercise requires you to return one of the equilibrium indices (or -1 if none found), not a generator, so the passing solution looks like:

```
def solution(A):
    sum_left, sum_right = 0, sum(A)
    for index, value in enumerate(A):
        sum_right -= value
        if sum_left == sum_right:
            return index
        sum_left += value
    return -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewritten as a generator function,

```
def solution(a):
    sum_left, sum_right = 0, sum(a)
    for index,value in enumerate(a):
        sum_right -= value
        if sum_left == sum_right:
            yield index
        sum_left += value
```

then to find all solutions,

```
list(solution([-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0]))    # => [3, 6]
```